# Advice for database implementation

Tags: database-recommendation, wordpress

We need to configure a database for our NGO. We have to save information about the children and several pictures and documents for each of them.

A friend is currently saving the data of over 70 kids in folders and subfolders of her device and it's becoming a mess. She asked me if I could digitalize it and I am not sure how I want to implement it.

We need the database and some kind of frontend where my friend can easily add, change or display information in the database without any IT knowledge. It would also be beneficial if we could connect our website to that database to display some pictures of the kids.

I've read about Wordpress and their database, is that a good solution? Or should I create our own MySQL database and a simple webpage where my friends has access to it?

I'm kinda new to databases but I really want to implement something that is better than our current storage situation. We are currently using a simple PHP, HTML, CSS, JavaScript website: [www.kencef.de](http://www.kencef.de). A friend and I are the only developers and aren't that experienced yet. Should we switch to Wordpress?

Answer (score 3):

> ... save information about the **children** and several **pictures** and **documents** ...
>
> ... A friend is currently saving the **data of over 70 kids** in folders and subfolders **on her device** ...
>
> ... We need the database ... frontend ... easily add, change or display informations ... **without any IT-knowledge** ...

I don't say this very often, but in this case, I don't think you *can* - or *should* - avoid it.

*Hire somebody* that knows what they're doing, *especially* in the fields of Data Security, Web Application Security, and who knows their way around the General Data Protection Regulations (GDPR) - at the very least.

The rules and regulations around Data Protection and Security and, more importantly still in your application, Safeguarding, etc., are **Legion** and you DO NOT want to get on the wrong side of them.

Question: What's does your Privacy Notice say?

If your answer is "What's a Privacy Notice", then you should not be *touching* this problem with a barge-pole!

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress is likely going to give you everything you need out of the box, especially if you guys don't have a lot of development experience. But if you want to take on the challenge of learning how to implement something yourself then you can try to create your own system. The design of the database side is relatively simple but it will definitely take a lot longer for you to implement your own system from scratch.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. I think that we will switch to Wordpress. I really wanted to implement it by myself but I don't have that much time due to university and my job :(

Comment: Yea usually it's a good idea to use what's been proven useful instead of reinventing the wheel, unless you're doing it for fun or learning purposes.